# Making multiple Async calls in a loop

Tags: silverlight-4.0, asynchronous, ria

I am loading (via drag and drop) multiple documents in a SilverLight 4 RIA application. The AddNewXDocument asyn call (in the code below) works great when i have just one record in the queue- i.e. _uploadedDocuments.Count =1. If I drop multiple files, however, the second AddNewXDocument method is called before the Submit event for the first file completes. I get the "A SubmitChanges operation is already in progress on this DomainContext" error.

How can I use IAsyncResult to delay calling the AddNewXDocument method for file 2 till after the Submit event for file 1 completes. Can I also tie in a visual indicator in the loop to inform user that a Load process is in progress ??

---

```
 foreach (var updDoc in _uploadedDocuments)
            {
                string docTitle = GetUniqueFileName(updDoc.Title.Replace(updDoc.FileExtension, ""), updDoc.FileExtension.ToLower()); 

                var doc = new XDocument();
                doc.Description = docTitle;          
                _myViewModel.AddNewXDocument(doc);
            }
```

Comment: Well i found an implementation in Strategy 2 on this link ... http://kuwamoto.org/2007/04/25/asynchronous-calls-explained/